# Manage "Low stock threshold" at Woocommerce products variations

Tags: woocommerce

I need to manage the "Low stock threshold" at Woocommerce products variations level, But default plugin (Woocommerce) does not have this functionality on product variations level.

It has a global level stock management Low stock threshold. But this is not what I want, because of my web full of variable/variations product. So I looking for a solution because I need to get notification about each product variation notification email when it hit the low stock threshold which I want to give.

Does anyone have a better suggestion for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have a specific value for each product variation? and when you hit it you will get a notice by email? Please share any code you already have made

Comment: No, I don't have a code for it. I'm looking code or plugin suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that WooCommerce allows for you to create webhooks for multiple types of events within their system. You can set up a webhook to send your app a request whenever any of the following events occur:

- Product created
- Product updated
- Product deleted

[Here is a link to WooCommerce webhook documentation.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/)

Essentially, you could use a webhook to notify your app when the stock of a particular product falls below your desired threshold. To do this, you would need to store a copy of the product in your own database, along with the threshold you want to be alerted at. If you received a webhook for 'Product updated' for when the stock level changes, you could write logic in your application to check your stock level you have set, and respond accordingly (such as a notification to an admin, an email, etc.).

[Here is a helpful article on setting up webhooks with WooCommerce.](https://growdevelopment.com/woocommerce-webhooks/)

Hopefully I have understood your problem correctly, and the setup you are implementing.